# Sorting Files by Name Containing Decimals

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have 200 files in my folder that I would like to sort by name. Here is a short list of my files according to the way that my Linux computer sorted them by default.

```
Name at 0.2142.png
Name at 0.4284.png
Name at 0.04284.png
Name at 0.6426.png
Name at 0.8568.png
Name at 0.08568.png
...
```

I would like to resort them by name from lowest to highest, so my list would become

```
Name at 0.04284.png
Name at 0.08568.png
...
Name at 0.2142.png
Name at 0.4284.png
Name at 0.8568.png 
...
```

(I put elipses in the middle of my list because there are many more files between Name at 0.08568.png and Name at 0.2142.png.)

I'm still new to writing bash files but I would think I could write one to sort my figures.

Thanks

Addendum:

Since the file names are so long I abbreviated them as Name at...
The real file name is **Planetary Vorticity Tilting by Radial Velocity at t =** with a number at the end. I hope you can understand why I didn't put that in the original question. I'm also pretty sure I said in the comments below that I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, I do not know "how" the file listing is created. I have a MatLab code that makes png files based off of my CFD data with the name that I provided above and the appropriate time step. When I open the folder on the Linux computer the files are automatically sorted in the way I listed above and I have no idea why.

If there is any other clarification needed I would be happy to put it here.

Comment: Specify language you writing code with, show your effort and exactly where you are stuck. Make sure to search for existing post about natural short.

Comment: I don't know what language I'm writing in. All I know is I need to open a terminal to write a bash file, and the version of Linux on this computer is 14.0.4. Also, I did look around for sorting questions, I did not find any where the file names had decimals. I would have thought a little more grace could've have been afforded to me when I said "I'm still new to writing bash files".

Comment: No the file names are rather long so in this example I made them name at. The files are listed in a default way after Matlab makes them.

Comment: No, they all start with the same string, the number is different. All I said was the name is long. The number represents the time, they are listed by default in a nonsensical order. The numbers don't go from decreasing to increasing.

Comment: @rici I can certainly give you the file names but they are long strings so I decided not to here. For good measure here is the longest file name (Planetary Vorticity Tilting by Radial Velocity at t=0.2142.png) and so on. I don't include the number when measuring the length of the file name.

Comment: @rici, would it be possible to converse about this somewhere else, I'm getting the warning about extended discussions.

Comment: @NWernerC456: I don't think you have enough rep to use chat. If you edit your question to provide real filenames, then I could have a go at answering it. Please also say how you are creating the file listing.

Comment: @NWernerC456: You still don't say how you are viewing the file listing. "When I open the folder" is not sufficient. When you open the folder *with what program, exactly*? Anyway, open a terminal session; use the `cd` command to navigate to the folder, type `ls` and see if the files come out in the correct order. Or figure out how to change the sort order in whatever program you're using to produce the file listing. There isn't just one, and they all have names, usually shown in the window title and/or the help menu.

Comment: @rici, I will look into this. I am running Ubuntu 14.0.4 on this computer, so when I open the folder, its the same as opening windows explorer to view files and folders on a PC. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @NWernerC456; Yes, on windows you are using a program called "Windows Explorer". But that doesn't exist on Ubuntu. Similarly, you are using some program, maybe Firefox or maybe Chrome, to read this page. If there is some problem viewing the page and you ask for help, people will reasonably ask you to specify "which web browser are you using", and if you are unable to answer that question, the help will be harder to come by. Similarly for file browsers. Sorry, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: @rici, I 100% understand but I did not set up this computer so I do not know the answer to this very fundamental question.

Comment: Well, perhaps this will help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38404/can-i-view-my-files-sorted-by-date (nautilus is the default file manager, iiui, but your machine might have something completely different). I'd look for a help button. There's usually one somewhere.

Comment: @NWernerC456 - just trying to help. How are you wanting the output to be presented? e.g. just pure terminal output? e.g. `ls | sort -n` and you get that 200 file names sorted and printed on your screen or do you want more? Like after getting the output you would like to delete file X , etc. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @SamuelToh, I just want to take unsorted files in their folder and resort them by number in the same folder if possible.

Comment: Is running `ls | sort -n` through the command line and get you a list of sorted directories sufficient or are you looking at customizing the way your UI displays the ordering of the directories? If it is for the latter then I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$files"
Name at 0.2142.png
Name at 0.4284.png
Name at 0.04284.png
Name at 0.6426.png
Name at 0.8568.png
Name at 0.08568.png
Name at 1.11.png
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$files" | sort -t.  -k1
Name at 0.04284.png
Name at 0.08568.png
Name at 0.2142.png
Name at 0.4284.png
Name at 0.6426.png
Name at 0.8568.png
Name at 1.11.png
```

That assumes the prefix `Name at` is the same in all cases.

Comment: Thank you dawg, should I write my bash file in the same folder as my pictures?

Comment: I cannot answer that. There are other considerations. Perhaps try a [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Comment: @NWernerC456 if this solved your problem you likely should accept the answer (clicking the check mark beside it) so others will know what worked for you and that there is already a solution to the question

Comment: I have not been able to implement it yet to see if it works

Comment: `-k1` here is redundant. The only issue with a standard sort is if there is more than one digit before the `.` so that you need a numerical sort rather than an alphabetical sort. Unfortunately, in order to use `-n` (numeric) you need to know where the number actually starts. That's not usually difficult but without knowing exactly what the filenames look like, it's certainly going to be tricky.